# Possibilities to compress an image (size)

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am implementing an application. In that I need to find out a way to compress the image (size). Because it will help a lot for me to making the space comfortable in the database(server).Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance,
Sekhar Behalam.

Comment: Don't store images inside a database

Comment: Hi,
@ klez:
 Thanks for your reply, But I am not saving them at my end I am just uploading the image to the server. What I am thinking is if I compress them at my end it will be very helpful for the server to adjust the large amount images. That's my problem. Do you have any suggession on this.

Thank you,
Sekhar Bethalam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options are to reduce the dimension of the images and/or reduce the quality by increasing the compression. Are the images photographic in nature (JPG is best) or simple solid colour graphics (use PNGs)?

If the images are JPG (lossy compression) you can simply load and re-save them with a higher compression setting. This can result in a large space saving.

The image quality will of course decline, but you can get away with quite a lot of compression in JPG before it is noticeable. What is acceptable of course is determined by the use of the images (which you have not stated).

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ HiTech Magic:

Hi,

I need to work for the JPG images, And I need to just upload them to the server. Let me try as you suggested.

Thanks for your great reply,
Sekhar Bethalam.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider pngcrush, which is a utility that is included with the SDK. In the Project Settings in Xcode, there's an option to "Compress PNG Images." Make sure to check that. Note that this only works for resource images (as far as I know)—but you haven't stated if these images will be user-created/instantiated, or brought into the app bundle directly.